# Payment made by LLC debit/credit card, but order placement done through a personal account

Tags: united-states, payment, limited-liability-company, accounting

I recently formed a multi-member LLC, opened its bank account and have its debit/credit cards.

To buy inventories for the business, I logged into eBay/Amazon using my personal account, and then bought some stuff using the LLC's debit/credit cards.

So, the payment is done through the LLC, but the order itself is placed under my personal account.

Is this allowed? I vaguely feel like the best practice is to create a merchant account under the business's name and deal with everything there. But as long as financial transactions are completely separated from my personal ones, the means through which the transactions occur shouldn't matter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch that is not a valid close reason!

Comment: I would argue that it *doesn't* belong on Money.SE, which seems to focus more on financial literacy and strategy. OP seems focused on what is legally permissible, which is obviously on topic here.

Comment: Of course, OP is also asking for legal advice, so that would be a more valid VTC.

Comment: Some online merchants require a separate account for making purchases that are not subject to sales tax. Inventory for a business might not be subject to sales tax. PurplePenguin should look into this.

Comment: @GerardAshton Thank you. I just realized that I could be tax-exempt when I buy inventories. To do so, the vendors indeed ask for the tax-exemption certificate. I will thus maintain a separate business account to make future purchases. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy things however you want, but cash outlays from the business should be from business accounts, which you have done.  No one cares what Amazon or eBay account you used to place the orders.  You won't find anywhere in your accounting software (or physical ledger book if you do it that way) a place to enter which account you used to place an order.  You just need the amount, purpose, and receipt.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to make sure. Thank you very much. It's now getting clearer for me. Thanks much!